# quadpy IntegrationError: Tolerances (abs: 1.49e-08, rel: 1.49e-08) could not be reached with the given max_num_subintervals (= 50)

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-integration, quad

I am using quadpy to integrate a function in python.

### Function

```
import numpy as np
T = 2*np.pi 

def ex1(t):
    return np.where(np.logical_and((t%T>=0), (t%T<np.pi)), t%T, np.pi)
```

The function is periodic, this is its plot:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 6*T, 1000)
plt.plot(x, ex1(x))
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Problem

I am trying to integrate this function:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import quadpy

print(quadpy.quad(ex1, 0, 3))
print(quad(ex1, 0, 3))
```

produces

```
(array(4.5), array(1.41692995e-19))
(4.5, 4.9960036108132044e-14)
```

On an interval from 0 to 3, everything works fine.
However If I increae the interval to e.g. 4, scipy still works.

```
print(quad(ex1, 0, 4))
```

produces

```
(7.631568411183528, 1.0717732083155035e-08)
```

but

```
print(quadpy.quad(ex1, 0, 4))
```

produces

```
IntegrationError: Tolerances (abs: 1.49e-08, rel: 1.49e-08) could not be reached with the given max_num_subintervals (= 50).
```

### Questions

- How do I prevent this error? I tried adding an argument called `max_num_subintervals` but that did not seem to work.
- Am I using quadpy correctly for what I am trying to do? I have begun using it since I wanted to take derivatives of complex numbers which scipy does not support, and I would like to have a one-size-fits-all solution, thus using quadpy for these easier examples that scipy would be enough.

Comment: Sounds like a bug that should be reported on github/quadpy. https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/issues

Comment: Hi, thanks for noticing my problem, I was hoping you would see my question! I have posted an answer that kind of prevents my problem, however I am unsure whether it is correct and why such a high tolerance is needed when scipy does not. Maybe you know more.

Comment: Like I said: Bug report! (This way I always see it.)

Comment: Ok, I will post it. edit: Done https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/issues/255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimenting I have found that quadpy's quad method takes the same argument as scipys quad method, which can be found here:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad

Using the `epsabs, epsrel, limit` optional arguments I can thus prevent the error:

```
print(quadpy.quad(ex1, 0, 4, epsabs=1e-1, epsrel=1e-1, limit=100))
```

produces

```
(array(7.6323447), array(0.01666253))
```

---

However scipys quad method reaches an error tolerance of `1-08`, which I really cant reproduce with quadpy, even when setting the limit to a really high value like `1000000`

Why is that?

---

Update: It seems the behaviour I experienced is a bug, now reported in: https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/issues/255

However in general this answer answers my initial question.

Comment: This is fixed now in quadpy.

Answer (score 1):

This was a quadpy bug after all. Fixed now:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import quadpy

T = 2 * np.pi


def ex1(t):
    return np.where(np.logical_and((t % T >= 0), (t % T < np.pi)), t % T, np.pi)


print(quadpy.__version__)
print(quadpy.quad(ex1, 0, 4))
print(quad(ex1, 0, 4))
```

```
0.14.7
(array(7.63156841), array(1.13827355e-16))
(7.631568411183528, 1.0717732083161812e-08)
```

You're probably using an outdated quadpy version.

Comment: I get the exact same results executing this code. Please try with `print(quadpy.quad(ex1, 0, 4))`, mine works with an interval from 0 to 3, but not 0 to 4. Other than that, quadpy version I have is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the update to quadpy 14.7, which solves the issue for intervals from e.g.0 to 4. However please try now with an interval from 0 to 7, or please see my comment in the github issue. Sorry for the inconveniences I'm causing, and thanks for your work!